# How to make 3d model from code and export it as .obj file

Tags: opencv, opengl, 3d, .obj

I'm trying to create a 3d model from script and then i want it to store it as .obj .fbx or .dae format is there any way that I could make it from OpenCV or OpenGL?

Comment: .obj format is very simple. You don't need any lib to store in it.

Comment: @МатвейВислоух can you please tell me how I'm going to do it and what software should I need?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @МатвейВислоух python

Comment: OpenCV is not a computer graphics library. it's a vision library. it currently doesn't deal with 3d geometry models.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def save_obj(vertex,index,uv=None):
    with open("/pathto/file.obj", 'w') as the_file:
        for v in vertex:
            the_file.write(
                'v ' + str(v[0]) + ' ' + str(v[1]) + ' ' + str(v[2]) + '\n')

        if uv is not None:
            for v in uv:
                the_file.write(
                    'vt ' + str(v[0]) + ' ' + str(v[1]) + '\n')
        for ind in index:
            the_file.write('f ' + str(ind[0] + 1) + '/' + str(ind[0] + 1) +'/ ' + str(ind[1]+1) + '/'+ str(ind[1] + 1) + '/ ' + str(ind[2]+1)+ '/'+ str(ind[2] + 1) + '/' + '\n')
```

Comment: Can you explain the code? What does it do?